# Android - Upload image along with request data

Tags: java, php, android, upload

I want to upload an image to my server through an android app however I would also like to pass other data along with the image (authentication, intention, etc.).

I have normally been making requests like so:

```
http://server/script.php?t=authtoken&j_id=12&... etc
```

However, I assume I cannot simply tack on another query parameter containing the byte array for the image as that would result in a URL with a size on the order of millions of characters.

```
&image=001101010010110111010001010101010110100101000101010100010... etc
```

I'm at a loss as to how I should approach this and would appreciate any suggestions. If I am not able to send the data through an http request, how would I handle the incoming data server-side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it work for those who may find this in the future.

For this example, let's say we want to query the PHP script `upload.php` on the root of `www.server.com` with the parameters `t=ABC123` and `id=12`. Along with this request, we also want to upload an image stored in the `java.io.File` object `img`. We will also be expecting a response from the server letting us know whether the upload was successful or not.

**ANDROID SIDE**

On the android side, you will need the following JARs:

```
apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar
```

Availabe [here](http://psg.mtu.edu/pub/apache//james/mime4j/) and:

```
httpclient-4.3.1.jar
httpcore-4.3.jar
httpmime-4.3.1.jar
```

Availabe [here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).

Here is a snippet on how to make the multipart request and get a response:

```
public String uploadRequest(String address, File img)
{
    HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
    p.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(p);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(address);

    // No need to add regular params as parts. You can if you want or
    // you can just tack them onto the URL as usual.
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.addPart("image", new FileBody(img));

    post.setEntity(builder.build());

    return client.execute(post, new ImageUploadResponseHandler()).toString();
}

private class ImageUploadResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<Object>
{
    @Override
    public Object handleResponse(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        return EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
    }
}
```

An example of using this method in the code (assume the variable `img` has already been declared containing the `File` object of the image you wish to upload):

```
// Notice regular params can be included in the address
String address = "http://www.server.com/upload.php?t=ABC123&id=12";

String resp = uploadRequest(address, img);

// Handle response
```

**PHP SIDE**

For the server-side script, the text params can be accessed normally through PHP's `$_REQUEST` object:

```
$token = $_REQUEST['token'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

And the image that was uploaded can accessed by using the information stored in the PHP `$_FILES` object (See the PHP docs for more info):

```
$img = $_FILES['img'];
```